# Slack Bolt Python modal not closing even though ack() is sent within 3 seconds

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

This is the function where I handle the view submission. I followed this [doc](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#view_submissions) for my development. As you can see, the `ack()` is called right after the password criteria check. I used the `time` package to check how long before the `ack()` is called and it is well below 3 seconds. However, this modal doesn't close and this error message:

> We had some trouble connecting. Try again?

The code after executes fine and the password resets

```
@app.view("reset_jc_password_view")
def handle_password_submission(ack, body, client, view, logger):
    """
    Handle reset password submission
    """
    start = time()
    new_pass = view["state"]["values"]["jc_reset_password_field"]["jc_reset_password_action"]["value"]
    user_id = body["user"]["id"]
    user_email = body["user"]["username"]

    # Password criteria
    errors = {}
    if len(new_pass) < 12 or not re.search("[a-z]", new_pass) or not re.search("[A-Z]", new_pass) or not re.search("[0-9]", new_pass):
        errors["jc_reset_password_field"] = "Password must contain at least 12 characters, at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 1 lowercase letter, at least 1 number, at least 1 symbol"
    if len(errors) > 0:
        ack(response_action="errors", errors=errors)
        return
    
    ack()
    now = time()
    print(f"Execution time: {now - start}")
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ack(response_action="clear")` for the bottommost ack